# Centering a right-justifed column under a heading of a table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have a table with a relatively long heading of one to two digit numbers. Here is my initial code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccr}
\toprule
\textnumero & Symbol & Number of Units \\ \midrule
1 & A & 9  \\
2 & B & 10 \\
3 & C & 7  \\
4 & D & 12 \\
5 & E & 2  \\
6 & F & 3  \\
7 & G & 4  \\
[![8 & H & 5  \\][1]][1]
9 & I & 5  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the whole table ends up looking rather unbalanced. Now, obviously, I could just center the whole column, like so:

```
...
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
...
```

[image]

The column is centered under the heading, but of course the numbers lose their right justification, which is less than ideal. My next intuition was to try to use the `\multicolumn` to try and get the heading centered, while leaving the rest right justifed:

```
...
\begin{tabular}{ccr}
\toprule
\textnumero & Symbol & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Number of Units} \\ \midrule
...
```

Unfortunately, this resulted in the same output as the first. I'm really not sure what I should do here. Is there any way to accomplish what I'm looking for? Ideally, the end result would look something like this (manually edited the screenshot in GIMP):

[image]

Comment: use dcolumn or siunitx packages and their decimal alignment columns (D or S respectively)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) `S`-column can align content in the way you want. Below I've used `table-format=2` to centre `2`-digit integers:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,textcomp,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ c c S[table-format=2] }
  \toprule
  \textnumero & Symbol & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Number of Units} \\
  \midrule
  1 & A & 1  \\
  2 & B & 22 \\
  3 & C & 3  \\
  4 & D & 44 \\
  5 & E & 5  \\
  6 & F & 66 \\
  7 & G & 7  \\
  8 & H & 88 \\
  9 & I & 9  \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Non-integer headers should be set using `\multicolumn{1}{<colspec>}{<header>}`.

---

Here is a comparable manual alternative, using `\phantom`s:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,textcomp}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ *{3}{c} }
  \toprule
  \textnumero & Symbol & Number of Units \\
  \midrule
  1 & A & \phantom{0}1  \\
  2 & B & 22 \\
  3 & C & \phantom{0}3  \\
  4 & D & 44 \\
  5 & E & \phantom{0}5  \\
  6 & F & 66 \\
  7 & G & \phantom{0}7  \\
  8 & H & 88 \\
  9 & I & \phantom{0}9  \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

---

Centered left-alignment is possible, but with a different approach. Below I've used [`collcell`](http://ctan.org/pkg/collcell) to `coll`ect each `cell` entry within the last column and examine it. If the number is less than 10, we add a `\phantom{0}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,textcomp,collcell}

\newcommand{\padright}[1]{#1\ifnum#1<10 \phantom{0}\fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ c c >{\collectcell\padright}c<{\endcollectcell} }
  \toprule
  \textnumero & Symbol & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Number of Units} \\
  \midrule
  1 & A & 1  \\
  2 & B & 22 \\
  3 & C & 3  \\
  4 & D & 44 \\
  5 & E & 5  \\
  6 & F & 66 \\
  7 & G & 7  \\
  8 & H & 88 \\
  9 & I & 9  \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

One would have to expand this manage wider elements as needed. For example, here's how to manage 100's:

```
\newcommand{\padright}[1]{#1%
  \ifnum#1<10 \phantom{0}\fi
  \ifnum#1<100 \phantom{0}\fi}
```

or 1000's:

```
\newcommand{\padright}[1]{#1%
  \ifnum#1<10 \phantom{0}\fi
  \ifnum#1<100 \phantom{0}\fi
  \ifnum#1<1000 \phantom{0}\fi}
```

Comment: Awesome! Just for future reference, is there any way to use the ``S`` column type to get centered left alignment?

Comment: @KevinKeith: Something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EItLV.png)?

Comment: yeah, exactly like that

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the full extent of the actual table, using right-aligned  `\Longstack`s for the data may suffice.

Note version `[2016-07-28]` of the package, which uses `\normalbaselineskip`, which is impervious to the `tabular` environment's redefinition of `\baselineskip`.  With an older version of the package, just add `\setstackgap{L}{\normalbaselineskip}` in the preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{stackengine}[2016-07-28]
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
\textnumero & Symbol & Number of Units \\ \midrule
\Longstack[r]{1  2 3  4 5 6 7 8 9}&
\Longstack[c]{A  B C  D E F G H I}&
\Longstack[r]{9 10 7 12 2 3 4 5 5}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]